# When I press a 'z' on the keyboard I want it to change the key "a" that had sound1.wav to now play a sound2.wav when pressed

Tags: javascript, audio, keyboard, keycode

So what I'm trying to accomplish is this:
Pressing 'a' on keyboard plays 'hello.wav'.
Pressing 'z' on keyboard changes the key 'a' to 'goodbye.wav'.
Now by pressing 'a' on keyboard it plays this 'goodbye.wav' instead of 'hello.wav'.

So in html I have a div of a bunch of audio id:

```
            <audio id="c1" controls style="display:none">
              <source src="hello.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>
```

and to trigger the sound is by pressing the key "a" which is keycode=65 and the javascript code is:

```
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 65) {
        document.getElementById('c1').play();
      }
    });
```

What I don't know how to do is that if I pressed key "z" then keycode == 65 would now play goodbye.wav instead of hello.wav:

```
     <audio id="ex1" controls style="display:none">
          <source src="goodbye.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could track if z was pressed using some flag, and on A key, play the approrpiate music. Hope I've understood your requirement correctly.

```
var enableGoodbye = false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    if (enableGoodbye === true)
        document.getElementById('ex1').play();
    else
        document.getElementById('c1').play();
  } else if (e.keyCode == 90) { //If Z, set flag to true
        enableGoodbye = true;
  }
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t8owxqo6/

Comment: Thanks! so z is pressed and enableGoodbye = true. How can I get it back to false if z is pressed again?

Comment: @Qwisatz In  that case, simply flip `enableGoodbye` instead of setting it to true i.e. instead of `enableGoodbye = true;`, use   `enableGoodbye = !enableGoodbye`. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t8owxqo6/2/

Comment: That's a little more complicated. In which order will they toggle? Or is it randomly pick one from a list?

Comment: Thanks! how could I get z to toggle a bunch of audio files instead.                                                                       1.pressing key 'a' plays 'c3.mp3' and pressing key 's' plays 'd3.mp3'                                                                              2.'pressing 'z' changes key'a' to play 'c2.mp3'. and also key's' to play d3.mp3.  http://jsfiddle.net/qwisatz/b5t5mb3v/